# filter incoming text from api jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

My system relies on fetching data from an API and then inserting the data into the jade template how ever one field is fetched with unirest and passed into jade like so

```
unirest.get('apiurl.com/endpoint')
.header('API-KEY', 'val1')
.header('Accept', 'text/plain')
.end(function(result) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: "Home",
        obj: result.body.target
    }
}
```

then calling `obj` in the view like so

```
p 
   #{obj}
```

which returns the text fromt the API however it returns it enclosed in brackets (`<>`)

my aim is to remove the `<` and `>` tags and keep the text inside

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I Fixed this by calling the variable using this line

```
p #{obj}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
p= obj
```

As you found out, `p #{obj}` works too. That's Jade's [string interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) syntax, which is useful when you want to put a variable in the middle of some other text (e.g. `h1 Hello #{name}!`), but when all you want inside the tag is the value of the variable, you should use `=` instead. See the documentation for [buffered code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/).

Comment: I see that, thankyou, however my main concern is with the string returning as `<123>` and i want to display it on the page as `123`

Comment: Yes, and my answer tells you the correct way to do that. The reason your string was being wrapped in `<>` is that it was the first thing on the line, which in Jade becomes a tag. With `p= obj` you will get a `<p>` tag with the value of `obj` inside it.